# I have liquids A,B, and C. B is soluble in both A and C, but A and C are insoluble in each other. If I add B to A and C, what happens?

Tags: solubility

My AP Chem class was doing a solubility lab, and I thought of something but did not have substances that fit the parameters to try it. I have three liquids, A,B, and C. A and C are insoluble in each other, but B is soluble in both. If I put A and C in a test tube, they should separate. If I add B to the tube, which will it dissolve in? Both? If only one, why?

Comment: If you knew the partition coefficient of this combination, you'd know. Or vice versa. ;) There will always be *some* B in both A and C. Law of mass action.

Comment: If we knew what A, B and C were, then we could do some educated guessing.

Comment: Theoretically, A and B and C will react to get new compounds -- like D and E, but **we don’t know if they react to each other**. We don’t have enough data to draw a conclusion:)

Answer (score 5):

Particular result will depend on liquids and their ratios.

Few principles to consider and apply:

- Let assume very low mutual solubility A-C and unlimited mutual solubility A-B and C-B.
- Initially, there is very little of A in C and vice versa.
- Small addition of B leads to distribution of B between A and C, keeping the ratio of concentrations of B in A, resp. C, according to the distribution constant.
- Simultaneously, mutual content of A in C and vice versa increases, as solubility of A in (C + B) and C in (A + B) increases.
- At some point, with progressive B addition, one of the above solubilities is able to absorb all the A or C liquid in the other phase, forming just the single phase, containing A + B + C.
- If B is not fully miscible with either of A or C, or neither of them, there is possible to have initially 2 to 3 phases, that transform to two or just one phase with huge B excess.